# sqlite massive insert with savepoint

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing an android application which needs at login moment to download a lot of data regarding some bookings. The first implementation was starting a transaction , saving all bookings, and committing the transaction at the end. This approach had appreciable performances, but the side effect was that sometimes users forcibly close the application, causing the loss of all saved data since that moment.
the approach I'm taking now is to save each booking in a transaction (because each booking intrest some tables), but the time it takes to save all data when there are a lot of bookings is longer than 15 minutes sometimes, which is too much. Is there any approach which can help me to get the inserts done quite fast without making a transacion for all data? Actually the code is this:

```
for (Booking _booking : bookings) {

            _booking.save();
        }
```

here is a pseudocode for save method

```
result=false;
try{
beginTransaction()

insert("table1",ContentValues)
insert("table2",ContentValues)
insert("table3",ContentValues)
insert("table4",ContentValues)

execSQL("SAVEPOINT " + this.bookingCode);
result = true;
}
catch{
execSQL("ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT " + lastSavePoint)
}

//this method commits or not depending on the result. I need to commit in any case 
//because i use beginTransactionWithListener in beginTransaction() function
endTransaction(result);
```

Comment: Off the cuff, one answer is to not download all that data in the first place, but instead access it on demand via a Web service. Another answer is to download the data at a more sensible time (e.g., 4am), or when the server indicates there are data changes (e.g., GCM).

Comment: by the moment I have all the database access syncronization implemented, can X simultaneos threads (eg:one for every 50 bookings) be faster?

Comment: "can X simultaneos threads (eg:one for every 50 bookings) be faster?" -- no, because only one thread can work with the database at a time. It's synchronized at the `SQLiteDatabase` level, and you cannot avoid this (particularly on Android 4.1+).